# In Cypress how to select input element based on name?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm starting to learn Cypress. I want to select the input field and provide the phone number by using cypress.io. The code I have following but it does not work. However can I using find or there is another way to get the input element to type in phone number?

```
cy.get('div').contains('Phone Number').find('input[name=teacher[0].number]').type('8000-1612023')
```

```html
<div class="required field">
  <label>Phone Number</label>
  <div title="Teacher number" class="ui fluid right labeled input no-spinners">
      <input required="" type="number" name="teacher[0].number" value="">
      <div class="ui label label">US</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cypress click element by ID / XPATH / Name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56886556/cypress-click-element-by-id-xpath-name)

Answer (score 28):

Why don't you directly target the input field using the following code

```js
cy.get('input[name="teacher[0].number"]').type('8000-1612023')
```

Please find the screenshot below for a successful test. I would also recommend you to change the type of input in your HTML to tel

#### HTML:

```html
<input required="" type="tel" name="teacher[0].number" value="">
```

#### Cypress:

```js
describe('Trial', function() {
  it('Test', function() {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:8080/trials/')
    cy.get('input[name="teacher[0].number"]').type('8000-1612023')
  })
});
```

#### Test Result:

[image: screenshot of cypress results]

Comment: ```cy.get('input[name="elementName"]').type(val)``` worked for me

Answer (score 8):

Try this instead:

```js
cy.contains('div', 'Phone Number').find('input').first().type('8000-1612023')
```

The first argument to `contains` tells cypress to find the element with that selector that contains the text.

Answer (score 2):

I write selectors with the input tag as below and it worked for me.

```
cy.get('input[name="elementName"]').type(val)
```

Check this to learn best practices when selecting elements:

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Selecting-Elements