# Cypress click element by ID / XPATH / Name?

Tags: automation, cypress

I want to click on an element by XPATH / ID and not the default cypress locator, is it possible?

In selenium I can use find element by XPATH for example:

```js
d.findElement(By.id("category")).click();
```

In Cypress it's:

```js
cy.get('#hdtb-msb-vis > :nth-child(3) > .category').click()
```

Can I click by ID?
*(It looks better in selenium!)*

```js
d.findElement(By.id("category")).click();
```

**VS**

```js
cy.get('#hdtb-msb-vis > :nth-child(3) > .category').click()
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Cypress, it works like this:

```
cy.get('button[id="category"]').click()
```

Notice that I just used button as an example here, you should replace that with the label of your element: div, select, textarea, etc...

Comment: Thanks ! how do I click by text ? say I have : <a href="javascript:onTTT_Button2('add','UserDetailsForm','action')">Add New User</a>  and I want to click by the text

Comment: I down voted because the question was 'using xpath' and the accepted solution does not use xpath.

Answer (score 23):

## Update for Cypress v 11

The answers are out of date, from version 11 Cypress core repo includes the `xpath` commands.

The install and usage are

## @cypress/xpath

Adds XPath command to Cypress.io test runner

#### Install with npm

```js
npm install -D @cypress/xpath
```

#### Install with Yarn

```js
yarn add @cypress/xpath --dev
```

Then include in your project's support file

```js
require('@cypress/xpath');
```

#### Use

After installation your `cy` object will have `xpath` command.

```js
it('finds list items', () => {
  cy.xpath('//ul[@class="todo-list"]//li').should('have.length', 3);
});
```

Comment: @cypress/xpath has also been deprecated and is no longer supported.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-xpath 
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/tree/develop/npm/xpath

Comment: Don't worry, if you want to use it the link is here [https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/tree/v11.2.0/npm/xpath](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/tree/v11.2.0/npm/xpath)

Answer (score 14):

I think, it is possible by adding a `plug-in` as suggested in Cypress website, please refer the following link `https://docs.cypress.io/plugins/#content`. If you refer the custom command section you could see `cypress-xpath` which takes you to following github link
  `https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-xpath`

```
npm install -D cypress-xpath
```

Then include in your project's cypress/support/index.js

```
require('cypress-xpath')
```

Sample usage given below:

```
it('finds list items', () => {
  cy.xpath('//ul[@class="todo-list"]//li')
    .should('have.length', 3)
})
```

Please try after installing the plug-in and updating the `support/index.js` file.

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer!

Comment: Thank you mate !

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 things to be done if trying to use xpath in cypress:-

1. In the file 'index.js' which sits under the folder 'YourProject'->'cypress'->'support', add the entry "require('cypress-xpath')"
2. In the file 'Dockerfile.cypress' which sits under the folder 'YourProject'->'configuration'->'docker', add the entry "RUN npm install cypress-xpath"

That's all you need to use all the xpath functions to uniquely identify all elements in your cypress tests.
I personally prefer using xpath since this gives me more control on the UI elements. Hope this will make life more easier in using cypress.

Answer (score 0):

`#hdtb-msb-vis` is an ID-selector and `.category` is a class-selector. But you should be able to select purely by the class-selector

```js
cy.get('.category')
  .click()
```

But if that class is not unique you can click it via the ID and then the class:

```js
cy.get('#hdtb-msb-vis')
  .find('.category')
  .click()
```

Comment: This is not what I've asked , I asked if Cypress can click by ID / XPATH instead of  class selector.

Comment: Makes me curious what kind of ID you are talking about, since `.category` is an CSS ID Selector, but apparently that is not the ID you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The first question contains two different selectors, the first (selenium) look for an id category and the second for a class category.

In fact :

```
d.findElement(By.id("category")).click();
==
cy.get('#category').click()
```

So yes you could select an element by it's ID !

> If (and i don't think) you want to have others possibility for selecting your elments look for jquery selector ([jquery is exposed in cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/$.html#Syntax))

Answer (score 0):

execute `npm install -D cypress-xpath`

If you using typescript. Add one file inside cypress/support/index.d.ts

Add
`import './commands'; import '../../node_modules/cypress-xpath';`

```
"types": ["cypress", "cypress-xpath"] in tsconfig.json
```

also add `import '../../node_modules/cypress-xpath`  in index.js file

Answer (score 0):

For ID use # and . for classes

```
cy.get('#category').click()
```

There is no direct way of using ID, Name, Class, tag name. Use css selector or various inbuild cypress commands to find the element.

For Xpath, There is no default support for XPath in Cypress. Follow below steps to install plugin and use it.

**Step 1:** Install XPath Plugin using below command

```
npm install cypress-xpath
```

or

```
yarn add cypress-xpath --dev
```

**Step 2** Add this line to index.js in **support** folder

```
require('cypress-xpath')
```

**Step 3** Add your xpath in xpath command like this

```
 cy.xpath("//input[@id='edit-name']").type('Naruto')
```

For Detailed steps with example refer [this](https://www.programsbuzz.com/article/cypress-xpath-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

[Should install xpath package and then add in Support/e2e.js. After that it will show suggestion to use xpath in .js file     ]
`cy.xpath('//body/div[@id="app"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/form[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]').contains('02').click()`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3L4r.png)

Answer (score 0):

I use Cypress v12+ and i just put

```
import "cypress-xpath"
```

inside of my e2e.ts file in the cypress/support directory. The other approaches did not work for me somehow. May be this is a thing with Cypress-Versions...

I think you can also import it in the testfile where you need xpath but inside the support-directory it has a global effect on every test-file.