# Cypress: How can I find by name

Tags: cypress

How can I get this input element by name?

```
<input min="0" class="" name="details["contactEmail"]" type="email" autocomplete="off" value="">
```

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
cy.get('[name="details["contactEmail"]"]').type('tara@gmail.com')
```

also this:

```
cy.get('[name="details[\"contactEmail\"]"]').type('tara@gmail.com')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Cypress how to select input element based on name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55716154/in-cypress-how-to-select-input-element-based-on-name)

Answer (score 0):

I also tried using a lot of combinations on the name attribute by escaping the characters but nothing worked. One suggestion that worked for me was to use the combination of the partial value of the `name` attribute and the `type` value. Something like:

```js
cy.get('[name*="details"][type="email"]').type('test')
```

Or, if you just want to use the name attribute or the type attribute, that works as well.

```js
cy.get('[name*="details"]').type('test')
cy.get('[type="email"]').type('test')
```